# Adding to page control collection from inside a user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an asp.net usercontrol which represents a "popup" dialog.  Basically, it's a wrapper for the jQuery UI dialog which can be subclassed to easily make dialogs.

As part of this control, I need to inject a div into the page the control is used on, either at the very top or very bottom of the form so that when the popup is instantiated, it's parent is changed to this div.  This allows "nested" popups without the child popup being trapped inside the parent popup.

The trouble is, I can't find a safe way to inject this div into the page.  A usercontrol doesn't have a preinit event, so I can't do it there, and calling Page.Form.Controls.Add(...) in Init, Load or PreRender causes the standard exception "The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases."

I thought I had found a solution by using...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Me.GetType, UniqueID + "_Dialog_Div", containerDiv, False)
```

... which seemed to work well normally, but recently a coworker tried putting an UpdatePanel inside the dialog and now she's getting the error "The script tag registered for type 'ASP.controls_order_viewzips_ascx' and key 'ctl00$ContentBody$OViewZips_Dialog_Div' has invalid characters outside of the script tags: . Only properly formatted script tags can be registered."

How are you supposed to add controls to the pages control collection from inside a user control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you really need to add this div to the page's form, but this should work:

```
  Public Class WebUserControl1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

        Private Sub UC_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
            AddHandler Me.Page.Init, AddressOf Me.Page_Init
        End Sub

        Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Dim dialogDiv As New Panel
            dialogDiv.ID = "DialogDiv"
            If Not Page.Form.Controls.Contains(dialogDiv) Then
                Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, dialogDiv)
            End If
        End Sub

    End Class
```

---

> How to implement it in C#. I'm always getting the error The control
>   collection cannot be modified on Load, PreRender 
>       I need a Literal Control to be added to my master page's head from a user control. The literal control will contain the css link.

Do you want to add the literal to the `HeadContent`-ContentPlaceHolder control in the master or to the page's header(the html head element)? However, here i show both.

Here's the codebehind of your `UserControl`:

```
public partial class UC_AddToMaster : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Page.Init += UC_AddToMaster_Init;
    }

    private void UC_AddToMaster_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Literal literal = new Literal{ Text = "Hi World!" };
        // if you want to add it to the header of the page:
        if (!Page.Header.Controls.Contains(literal))
        {
            Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, literal);
        }

        // if you want to add it to the master's HeadContent ContentPlaceHolder control:
        var siteMaster = Page.Master as SiteMaster;
        if (siteMaster != null)
        {
            if (!siteMaster.Head.Controls.Contains(literal))
            {
                siteMaster.Head.Controls.AddAt(0, literal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the `HeadContent` approach mentioned above i've provided following property in the master:

```
// in the master
public ContentPlaceHolder Head { get { return this.HeadContent; } }
```

Therefore i needed to cast the page's master to it's actual type(`SiteMaster` here) in the `UserControl`. Otherwise i couldn't access this property.

Comment: You can't alter the page control collection in Page Init.  Also, controls already have the init event so registering isn't necessary.  If you meant PreInit then I don't know when the control could register a PreInit event since the first event it has access to is Init?

Comment: Have you tried it? The panel will be rendered as a div on the page with this code. I have added a handler for the page's init event because you can't add controls in the usercontrol's init event to the page's form, because on this time the form will be nothing(usercontrol's init fires before page's init).

Comment: I hadn't tried it and yes, it works!  Thanks.  I'm still baffled at the difference between the Page Init event (where you can't change the control collection?) and an event handler attached to the Page Init event (where you can?) but I can't argue with results.

Comment: There is a small but important difference. If you handle the "page's" init event, you aren't handling the page's init event directly. Actually you're handling the usercontrol's init event and that is fired before the page itself. So you wanted to change the control collection of a page that is yet not fully intialized. By adding the event-handler you ensure that the div will added directly after the page was intialized and before page_load. Here are some interesting details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations
Glad i could help.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I have to be honest, this is some of the craziest trickery I've ever seen. Oh, it works, but man it's insane!

Comment: asp.net version of this please? :(

Comment: @FahadAbidJanjua: ASP.NET 1.1

Comment: @TimSchmelter I meant how to implement in C#. Sorry for the confusion. Always getting the error The control collection cannot be modified on Load, PreRender, etc

Comment: I need a Literal Control to be added to my master page's head from a user control. The literal control will contain the css link

Comment: @FahadAbidJanjua: Edited my answer to provide the solution. Next time you should better ask your own question because the answer is getting confusing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for such a great courtesy. Your first solution is working fine and second solution just inserts literal control in MasterPage's HeadContent ContentPlaceHolder. Is there anyway to insert literla control in MasterPage's html head tag?

Comment: @FahadAbidJanjua: The `MasterPage` is a child control of the `Page`, so actually only the page will have a head, the master will be merged with the content-page. So it works with the page's `Header` property  as   shown above. If you want to access the master's head control anyway you can use the same approach as with the `HeadContent`. Therefore you need to give the master's head an ID. Then you can add a property which returns this head: `public System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead Head { get { return this.MasterHead; } }`. The part in the usercontrol is the same as with the `HeadContent`.

Comment: yeahh done it like you mentioned. Thanks alot for your time and help :)

Answer (score 4):

Usercontrol doesn't have a PreInit event, but nothing's stopping you from adding a handler to the Page PreInit event in your UserControl:

```
Page.PreInit += new EventHandler(Page_PreInit);
```

edit - you're right - you can't capture PreInit from a usercontrol, though I'm surprised you can't - but you can still change the page controls collection by adding code to the constructor of the UserControl. I tried this and it works.

```
public MyUsercontrol()
{
    Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    Literal lit = new Literal();
    lit.Text="text";
    page.Controls.Add(lit);
}
```

Adding an event handler to Page.PreInit in the constructor compiles but it never fires.

(end edit)

That said, I'm not exactly sure why this is necessary to achieve your goal. Why don't you just have your dialog control render it's own div in-line wherever you drop it into the form, and use that as the parent, instead of trying to create one somewhere else in the form? I can't think of why it would be important for it to physically be rendered at the beginning or end of the form. It's a dialog so it will always be invisible until you use it, right?

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  The earliest event that a control has access to is Init, so where would I put this line of code to register the PreInit event?  I could do that on the page, but that would kind of defeat the purpose of using the control.  I'm injecting the div like this because I had a problem with jQuery UI which meant that opening one dialog from another dialog caused the second to be embedded in the first rather than independent.

Comment: Edited answer. But still the basic point about why you need to do this remains. If your jQuery code can figure out to use the single div that the usercontrol added to the main page, why couldn't it figure out to use the same div added inline by the parent? I don't understand why it is important where the div appears. The jquery ought to be able to figure out if it's already inside one and use an existing div wherever it appears.

Comment: By the way I'm sorry I'm giving examples in C# (I didn't notice until now it was VB) but I assume the same would work with VB syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Getting the page reference from HttpContext is really interesting; I've not seen that before.  The control's page property is null during the constructor so I didn't think you could attach an event at that point.  No problem with C# / VB - I'm used to translating at this point :)  I'm afraid Tim beat you to the bounty but thanks for your input.

Comment: The control's page property is null, but since you can  get the page reference from the HttpContext, I had tried to attach a PreInit event to it in the constructor. Which seems like it should work, but perhaps it has already fired, though I am surprised that any events would fire before the constructors of child objects run.. In any event it does indeed let you modify the controls collection from the constructor. No  worries about the bounty, I'm not in it for the money :)