# How to get a custom control available for use in an ASP.NET Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an **ASP.NET Website**, not Web Application, and I've built a custom `CompareValidator` that's capable of getting outside of it's own naming container:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

public class GlobalCompareValidator : CompareValidator
{
    new protected void CheckControlValidationProperty(string name, string propertyName)
    {
        Control control = this.Page.NamingContainer.FindControl(name);
        if (control == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException("Validator_control_not_found");
        }
        if (BaseValidator.GetValidationProperty(control) == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException("Validator_bad_control_type");
        }
    }
}
```

and that code exists in the `App_Code` directory. Now, I want to use this new custom control on an ASCX page like this:

```
<me:GlobalCompareValidator ID="compareValidator" CssClass="errorMessage" Display="None"
    EnableClientScript="false" Text="&nbsp;" ValidationGroup="LHError" runat="server" />
```

however, when attempting to register the assembly to use it:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="me" Namespace="MyNamespace" Assembly="MyAssembly" %>
```

I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly '...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Now,** that's not really all that surprising because an ASP.NET Website doesn't really generate an assembly like that. However, if I leave the `Assembly` tag off it can't find `GlobalCompareValidator`. Sure, it probably can't find it with the `Assembly` tag either, but that error is likely hidden by the fact that it can't find the assembly.

How in the world do I get a custom control available for use in an ASP.NET Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the solution to this problem is convoluted, but here it goes. First, after spending a significant amount of time trying to get the custom control to work I decided to change the way I was thinking about the problem. I said:

> What if I could get the control in the right naming container instead?

Seems straight forward enough! At runtime, we'll remove the control from the user control and add it to the user control's parent. But, that's a lot more convoluted than it seems. You change modify the `Controls` collection in `Init` or `Load`, so that's a bit problematic for the idea. But, alas, Stack Overflow came to the rescue [by way of the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975823/adding-to-page-control-collection-from-inside-a-user-control/4997905#comment24206514_4997905)! So, armed with that I added the following code to the user control:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.Init += PageInit;
}

protected void PageInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ControlToCompare))
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(this.compareValidator);
        this.Parent.Controls.Add(this.compareValidator);
    }
}
```

What you have here is a little loophole in the page life cycle. Though I can't modify the `Controls` collection in `Init` or `Load`, I can modify it in between those two events! Thanks Tim!

This accomplishes the task, in that I'm able to move the `CompareValidator` to the proper naming container at runtime so that it can find the user control it's validating against.

**NOTE:** you also have to tack the `ValidationProperty` attribute onto the user control you want to compare your value to. I did it like this:

```
[ValidationProperty("Value")]
```

and then of course there is a property named `Value` that's exposed on that user control. In my case that attribute went on the same user control I was modifying for the `CompareValidator` because I was comparing two values from the same user control.

I hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Register directive for two purposes:

1. Including a UserControl
2. Including a Custom control

The SRC-attribute is only needed if you're including a UserControl. In your case, you're using a custom control so you only need the Namespace and the Assembly-attributes.

You can check this MSDN-page for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1(v=vs.71).aspx